# how to run windows app via ssh on specific display

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd.exe

I've installed Bitvise ssh server on my windows 10. Now I'd like to run .exe file via ssh. But since bitvise runs as a service it starts in background and I want it to be displayed on my desktop. On linux host I always used `-display :0` argument, however I couldn't find any alternatives on windows. Can you help me with that ? Also I've tried `/runas /user:` command but it has the same effect

Comment: don't know, but i'd note that i've heard of a similar issue with VNC where on linux you can choose what desktop to view, whereas on windows you can't. Though windows does have programs like goscreen or virtuawin that give virtual desktops.